# using google maps api to show locations with multiple custom marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am a JavaScript newbie . i am currently experimenting with a small google map based task.i have a large set of latitude and longitudes, around thousand and for each set of latitude and longitude pair i have some value which is gained from some servey . i can catogorize  each value  something like excellent, good or bad

Now for above scenario what i want to do is show all the categorized value in the specific latitudes and longitudes and use different custom marker for excellent ,good or bad value.my question is can i use Google maps api without key and how can i use multiple color based custom  marker to show all the latitudes and longitudes 
Is there any limit to use custom marker in maps

A help would be appreciated

Comment: there is no limit for custom markers, the API may be used without a key.

Comment: [example categories map with different icon for each category](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html)